# Working with both MVC and a WebApi-projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, umbraco

We have this web.api-project currently residing in `api.mydomain.com`. It is as a backend for a mobile app and also a superadminlike javascript application. We also have this new public facing website (using Umbraco CMS, in the same VS-solution) wich currently holds just your plain information (with pages like "about us", "get the app" etc) on `www.mydomain.com`

We've setup a asp.net membership across theese domains and are now looking to find a way to have the public site host pages like login, edit profile, start subscription etc. **The controller(s) for theese views exist in the web api-project. Views would presumably exist in the MVC-project.**

I am not sure what approach to take. I would preferably be able to use the viewmodels that already exists in the solution and leverage the whole Modelstate/validation-thing, returning `View()` from the WebApi-project etc.

We could make our edit profile-forms just to POST to the api-project (CORS is a no-go), but then the api project would have to use the hackish Request.CreateResponse in order to redirect the user to some hardcoded place back on the public site, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I've used web-api to talk back and forth to a front-end umbraco site I've tried to make it as dumb as possible and that seems to work well.  It feels wrong to couple up you web-api project to do more than send data when requested, using web-api controllers to affect the UI/Views of a website sounds wrong.

Have you considered using Umbraco Members & then configuring them to use asp.net membership (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers/how-to-integrate-aspnet-membership-control-with-umbraco) - in that way the Umbraco front-end can deliver tailored stuff to asp.net membership authenticated users without all the to-ing & fro-ing from your web-api?